# Is there a Python Isomap module that accepting distance matrix as well as original vectors?

Tags: python, machine-learning, visualization

[Isomap in well-known scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.Isomap.html) only accepts plain vectors as input. But I only have a distance matrix. Is there any other Python module handling this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isomap is a two step process:

1a. Given the original data points, find nearby neighbors.
1b. Compute a distance matrix D based on distances between points when you are only allowed to hop between nearby neighbors.

2. Run Multidimensional Scaling on the distance matrix D.

Notes:
1. If you already have a distance matrix D, you can just skip to step 2.
The multi-dimensional scaling algorithm is also in sklearn: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html

2. If you distance matrix is computed as the Euclidean distance between the original points (and not, for example, some shortest path hopping distance), then the output of MDS on this gives the same results as the PCA embedding of the original points.
3. If you have the Euclidean distance matrix, but you want the Isomap embedding instead of the PCA embedding, then you need to do the nearest neighbors and shortest path computation.  This might entail:

a. For each point, find the k-closest points, and set the distance to all other points to infinity to create a new matrix D'.
b. Run Dijkstra's all pairs shortest path on D'.
c. Run MDS on D'.

Good luck!

Comment: I forgot the final step is just MDS! Thank you so much!